# I do not see any text when i called the function

Tags: javascript, html

I have `index.html` & `index.js`. In my `index.js` file, I am trying to get `Id`, and according to `id`, I want to add new titles & text by calling the function. I could not do accomplish so far. What is my mistake? Also, I tried to add `js` file path to the head, did not work. After that, I tried it in the body, did not work as well. This is my last attempt.

Here is my code

*index.js &*index.html*

```js
var test = function() {
    var section = document.getElementById("unit-price");
    var span_1 = document.createElement("span");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Unit Price: ");
    span_1.appendChild(text);
    section.appendChild(span_1);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script src="index.js">test();</script>
      <div id="unit-price"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Call your `test` function in the JS file after function declaration. Remove it from `script` tag.

Comment: @PrerakSola To able to see text, i needed to `script` tag to end of the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your `test` function after declaration in your JS file.

If a [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) element has a src attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags.

```js
var test = function() {
    var section = document.getElementById("unit-price");
    var span_1 = document.createElement("span");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Unit Price: ");
    span_1.appendChild(text);
    section.appendChild(span_1);
}

test();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
      <div id="unit-price"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried both you said both still i do not see any result

Comment: @KaanTahaKöken You can see the solution is working here when you click on the `Run Code Snippet` button. Kindly check your code thoroughly.

Comment: @KaanTahaKöken Sorry, I did a mistake while copying your code. You can check the updated code now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `<script>` tags refer to an external source and contain inline code.

You'd need to execute the function in a new script tag:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>
  test();
</script>
```

or add it to your index.js:

```
var test = function() {
var section = document.getElementById("unit-price");
var span_1 = document.createElement("span");
var text = document.createTextNode("Unit Price: ");
span_1.appendChild(text);
section.appendChild(span_1);
}
test();
```

Comment: I tried both you said both still i do not see any result

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below.

```js
var test = function() {
    var section = document.getElementById("unit-price");
    var span_1 = document.createElement("span");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Unit Price: ");
    span_1.appendChild(text);
    section.appendChild(span_1);
}
test();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="unit-price"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

or you can also do this

```
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
    test();
</script>
```